# Reboot crontab not working on reboot

Tags: cron

This is the crontab: `@reboot cd /var/test/ && php gearman_test.php`

but whenever I ssh and run `ps -aux | grep .php` I cannot see `gearman_test.php`

If I copy paste the command (without the @reboot) it works from any directory.

if I now run `ps -aux | grep .php`  I see `gearman_test.php`

the syslog is showing:
`Apr 11 17:11:48 server CRON[2441]: (root) CMD (cd /var/test/ && php gearman_test.php)`

I also tried adding an `&` at the end but it didn't work.

Comment: Instead of `php`, use `/bin/php`  or whatever comes from `which php`. Also, it is better to execute with full path: `/bin/php /var/test/gearman_test.php`

Comment: execution with full path would not work because of the requires() inside the gearman_test.php file

Comment: and it still didn't work